# Sample Ext Js state provide?

Tags: html, extjs4, web-storage, session-state-provider

Can anyone tell me sample of Ext JS provider, a specially if it intends to use any HTML 5
storage mechanism.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ext.state.Provider` is an abstract base class for state provider implementations. The current version of ExtJS has just one storage provider namely [CookieProvider](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.state.CookieProvider.html).

You can create your on storage provider by inheriting the Provider class and implement HTML 5 storage mechanism. Here is a possible skeleton code:

```
Ext.define('Ext.state.LocalStoreProvider', {
    extend: 'Ext.state.Provider',

    constructor : function(config){
        // 1. set default values
        // 2. Check if HTML5 storage is supported?
        // 3. load existing values
    },


    set : function(name, value){
        localStorage.setItem(name, value);
    },

    get : function(name,default) {

        var val = localStorage[name];
        if(val)
            return val;
        else
            return default; 
    },

    clear : function(name){
        localStorage.removeItem(name);  
    },

    decodeValue : function( val) {

        // Logic to decode an encoded data
    },

    encodeValue : function( val) {

        // Logic to encode a string data
    }

});
```

**Note: This code is not complete, nor tested and requires more logic before being executed. This can be used as a starting point.**